# Как корректно отобразить данные из файла json на HTML странице ( переключая значения на самой html странице)

Tags: javascript, html, json

Как корректно отобразить данные из файла json на HTML странице (в том числе переключая на HTML значения)

содержимое файла `data.json`:

```json
data = {
    "Сергей": {
        "возраст": 34,
        "пол": "мужской"
    },
    "Марат": {
        "возраст": 39,
        "пол": "мужской"
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--> <script src="script.js"></script> -->

</body>

</html>

    <tr>
        <th><label for="id_name">Выберите имя:</label></th>
        <td>
            <select name="regime" id="id_name">
                <option value="здесь должно быть имя № 1"></option>
                <option value="здесь должно быть имя № 2 и тд"></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th><label for="age">Возраст:</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="age" id="age">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="sex">пол:</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="sex" id="sex">
        </td>
    </tr>

<!-- end -->

    <!--  My_script_Test  -->
    <script>

        // 1. method: read local file and show them in console.log
        fetch('./data.json')  // read local_json_file
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })

    </script>
```

[image: пример страницы]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Завести переменную `data`. При погрузке данных с файла их закинуть в переменную. И добавить динамически `option`  справильными атрибутами в `select`
2. Повесить слушателя (`addEventListener`) на `select` на событие `change`, при выборе данных в нём, оперировать даннами из переменной `data`
3. В принципе всё.

Comment: Спасибо  Вам,  попробую ))

Comment: Правильно ли будет держать данные в переменной? Если будет большой объем или данные изменяться в файле?

Comment: @PavelNazarian Всё зависит от ситуации. Для базового освоения навыков работы как у автора - такое решение вполне хорошее.

Comment: @almaz на выбор, кстати, если чисто для учебного задания - то можно в select сразу задать нужные значения, либо при подгрузке данных сформировать `option` с данными  и вставить в `select` типа такого https://learn.javascript.ru/task/add-select-option (только есессно в цикле)

Comment: благодарю за направление ))

Comment: А разве можно так коротко отвечать?

Comment: @PeterKolosov если у вас ограничение по символом для ваших ответов, то вам - нельзя!))

Comment: ахахах)))))))))